# How to show PART_Indicator when value is 0 in a ProgressBar? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ProgressBar` with a custom style, I'm trying to show a ellipse at the beginning of the Bar, but when the `ProgressBar.Value = 0` the ellipse is not shown, only when the `ProgressBar.Value > 5`, is there a way to force that PART_Indicator to show the ellipse?

Here a complete and reproducible example, just click on the start button and it will start the timer:

Any Ideas are welcome, thanks in advance!

Code-behind:

```
namespace ProgressBar
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;

        private TimeSpan _estimatedTotalTime;

        private bool _isIndeterminate;

        private DispatcherTimer _progressBarTimer;

        private double _timeProgress;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
        {
            get => _elapsedTime;
            set
            {
                _elapsedTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan EstimatedTotalTime
        {
            get => _estimatedTotalTime;
            set
            {
                _estimatedTotalTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsIndeterminate
        {
            get => _isIndeterminate;
            set
            {
                _isIndeterminate = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DispatcherTimer ProgressBarTimer
        {
            get => _progressBarTimer;
            set
            {
                _progressBarTimer = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double TimeProgress
        {
            get => _timeProgress;
            set
            {
                _timeProgress = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        private void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            EstimatedTotalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
            ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan();

            ProgressBarTimer = new DispatcherTimer(
                                   new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),
                                   DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                   OnTick,
                                   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher) {
                                                                    IsEnabled = false 
                                                                 };
            ProgressBarTimer.Start();
        }

        private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));

            if (ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds.Equals(EstimatedTotalTime.TotalSeconds))
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true;

                return;
            }

            TimeProgress = ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds * 100 / EstimatedTotalTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ProgressBar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgressBar"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LevelMeterProgressBarStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBDBDBD" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF348781" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Grid Name="TemplateRoot">

                            <Rectangle Name="PART_Track"
                                       Height="5.5"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

                            <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                               Height="5.5"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

                                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="1"
                                             Width="33"
                                             Height="33"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                             Stretch="Fill" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Decorator>

                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    CornerRadius="2" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Click="OnStart"
                Content="Start" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00} / {3:00}:{4:00}:{5:00}">
                    <Binding Path="EstimatedTotalTime.Hours" />
                    <Binding Path="EstimatedTotalTime.Minutes" />
                    <Binding Path="EstimatedTotalTime.Seconds" />
                    <Binding Path="ElapsedTime.Hours" />
                    <Binding Path="ElapsedTime.Minutes" />
                    <Binding Path="ElapsedTime.Seconds" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
        <ProgressBar Margin="20"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate}"
                     Maximum="100"
                     Minimum="0"
                     Style="{DynamicResource LevelMeterProgressBarStyle}"
                     Value="{Binding TimeProgress}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution is to set `MinWidth="33"` on the `"PART_Indicator"` - `MinWidth` takes precedence over `Width`, so the ellipse will always be fully visible. The downside of this approach is that the ellipse will remain "stationary" until the value is high enough so that the indicator's total width is higher than the width of the ellipse (I think it was 5 in your case), which I assume is undesirable.

The key to the solution lies in moving the ellipse outside of `"PART_Indicator"`, as mentioned by @GenericTeaCup. The idea is to set horizontal margin to the track bar and indicator equal to half the width of the ellipse, so that its left and right sides are exactly under the ellipse's center point when value is minimum and maximum correspondingly. That way we can easily move the ellipse by the indicator's actual width and have it always at the exact spot we want it to be (centered directly over the indicator's right side). Now I am not sure what are your exact expectations regarding the start and the end of the track bar, so I'll give you two options I consider most common.

First one looks like this (I've added some transparency to the ellipse so that the difference is clearly visible):

[image: Start]

[image: End]

This template should produce depicted result:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
        <Rectangle x:Name="LeftFill" Height="5.5" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="RightFill" Height="5.5" Width="17" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Height="5.5" Margin="16.5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" Height="5.5" Margin="16.5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <Ellipse Width="33" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Source={x:Reference PART_Indicator}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The second option is this:

[image: Start]

[image: End]

In order to get it you simply need to remove `"LeftFill"` and `"RightFill"` from the template. Note that the track bar will seem indented in relation to the `ProgressBar` itself.

If you're uncomfortable with using `RenderTransform` on the ellipse you can alwas put it in a `Canvas` and bind `Canvas.Left` property instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think this in not easy. The width of the progressbar indicator is set per this formula in a private method:

```
 this._indicator.Width = (this.IsIndeterminate || maximum <= minimum ? 1.0 : (num - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)) * this._track.ActualWidth;
```

You will have to write your own custom progressbar based on [RangeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was afraid of that, but I think is the only soluton as I have tried almost everything.

Comment: Well, I could think of another solution: Take the ellipse out of the "PART_Indicator" Decorator and calculate it's position according to the progressbar value...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in my basic understanding, this will have to be done with the ellipse inside a canvas which already contains the progress bar, and the use transform to write the pixel x where the bar is, right?

Comment: Yes. Make sure to set the canvas z-index for the ellipse to be always on top.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implemented that way